# Class/ function result use in following code

Tags: javascript, function, class, return

I am a beginner in javascript and am now trying to understand the subject of classes. I've defined the following class. Now I would like to use the result outside of this in a variable.

The class looks like this:

```
class Maad{
constructor(name, NumWeek, NumMonth){
    this.name =name;
    this.NumWeek = NumWeek;
    this.NumMonth = NumMonth;
}

queryMaad(){
    const mongodb =require('mongodb');
    const client = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const url= 'mongodb://localhost:27017/vertrieb';
    client.connect(url,(error, db) =>{
        if(!error){
            console.log("month_log steht")
        };

        let col = db.collection("umsatz5");
        col.aggregate([{'$match': {'AD': this.name}}, {'$match': {'Kalenderwoche':this.NumWeek}}, {'$count': 'procjetnumber'}],function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                console.error("Error calling", err);
            }

            console.log(result[0].projectnumber);
           result[0].projectnumber;
           

        })
        db.close();
    });
}
```

}

My request is:

```
let ma_1 = new Maad("Hans Wurst", NumWeek);
ma_1.queryMaad();
```

How can I save the result (the number of projects) in a variable to use it outside of the class? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to return something from your method.  It's `void` right now.  But this mongdb `connect` function with its callbacks is confusing, so that's harder than it sounds.  You would have some top-level variable which you set from within the success callback. 
 But `connect` is not async so detecting when then happens is harder.  Also I would move all your `require` imports to the top of the file.

Comment: You would have to create your own `Promise` that you resolve or reject.  I'll take a stab at it, but what's shown in the mongodb docs conflicts with what's in the typescript definitions so I'm kinda confused by the data types.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would assign it basically the way that you assign anything:

```
const ma_1 = new Maad("Hans Wurst", NumWeek);
const myVar = ma_1.queryMaad();
```

However your method is a `void` method which doesn't return anything, so you need to edit your class if you want to get the number of projects.

Returning something from the function is harder than it sounds because `MongoClient.connect` is a `void` method which uses callbacks rather than returning a `Promise` of a response.  Honestly I would recommend using a library like [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose).  But it is possible to make the method asynchronous ourselves by returning a [`new Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) which we resolve or reject based on the callbacks.

```
class Maad {

  constructor(name, NumWeek, NumMonth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.NumWeek = NumWeek;
    this.NumMonth = NumMonth;
  }

  async queryMaad() {
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/vertrieb";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoClient.connect(url, (error, db) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }

        console.log("month_log steht");
        let col = db.collection("umsatz5");
        col.aggregate(
          [
            { $match: { AD: this.name } },
            { $match: { Kalenderwoche: this.NumWeek } },
            { $count: "procjetnumber" }
          ],
          function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }

            resolve(result);
          }
        );
        db.close();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Now `queryMaad` is an `async` method, one which returns a `Promise`.  That `Promise` will resolve to the result of `col.aggregate` on success (you could also resolve to `result[0].projectnumber`).  The promise will reject if there is an error in the `connect` or `col.aggregate` methods.

You now get your value like so (probably inside of a function which is itself `async`):

```
const result = await ma_1.queryMaad();
```

You can `catch` rejection errors here, or allow them to be thrown and catch them higher up.

```
try {
  const result = await ma_1.queryMaad();
} catch (error) {
  // console.error or whatever
}
```